# SSRS Report Manager (2008R2) will not save Windows credential password in data source

Tags: reporting-services, credentials, ssrs-2008-r2, reportmanager

On a test server, we have a data source using "Credentials stored securely in the report server" and "Use as Windows credentials when connecting to the data source". The account is a domain account. If I enter the password and click "Test Connection" I get "Connection created successfully" but the password box empties and when I click "Apply", the password isn't saved.

I have all rights on the folder and am set up as a Systems Administrator role in Site Settings.

Our other test servers are set up the same way and I don't have a problem with them. A coworker with the same rights as me has no problem with this server. All of them have the data sources set up to use the same domain account. So the problem is only it is me working with this one server. It worked fine for the last year and just stopped working this week. So something must have changed, but I can't figure out what.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

If you move a report (copy/paste) the report credentials have to be re-entered. This data is not saved in the definition itself.

Comment: I haven't moved anything. I am discussing entering the credentials in the data source, not the report.