# SSRS Update Data Sources always reports "The password is not valid. Please retype the password."

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

On SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard edition whenever I try and update Data Source credentials via the Report Manager I cannot save the changes as it reports the message

> "The password is not valid. Please retype the password".

I've looked online and someone thought it could be related to a known issue in Chrome.  Unfortunately I've tried Chrome/I.E 11 and Firefox and they all report the same issue.  I am choosing the "Credentials stored securely in the report server" option.

Has anyone any idea to work around this?

This could be similar: [SSRS Report Manager (2008R2) will not save Windows credential password in data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452339/ssrs-report-manager-2008r2-will-not-save-windows-credential-password-in-data-s)

Comment: Are you storing Windows or SQL user credentials, and have you tried the inverse?

Comment: Neither (I think...)...the credentials are for an ODBC connected database (different dbms) sitting through a linked server.  I don't think the problem is with the credentials, it acts like it is validating the password on every key press or something (almost like javascript or jquery is causing the problem)

Comment: Hmm. Can you provide a screenshot of the config you're testing, and what domains the SSRS server and SQL server you're connecting to exist on?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your SSRS DataSource points to a SQL Server that has a linked server to an ODBC connected database?   Or is your SSRS DataSource pointing directly to the ODBC connected database and you used the term "linked server" loosely?

Comment: You understand correctly, it is pointing to the linked server and then the ODBC (although I have now created a direct ODBC data source and that experiences the same problem (when I try and enter the details (not even on the username/password text boxes) it always states the password is invalid)).

Comment: Does the linked server work correctly when used from SSMS?

Comment: Yeah works fine ;( it seems to be report manager specific ( if I use old credentials they work... It's just trying to update via the report manager

Comment: Tried  IE and it didnt work. changing to windows, saving , then changing back did.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ultimately it was a browser/javascript issue I think..

There was nothing I could do to force the password to be saved using the form as it is designed.

The only work around I found was I had to switch focus between the three radio button options ("Credentials stored securely in the report", "windows integrated security "and "Credentials Not required") and then test the connection (it fails).  Then I had to switch back to "Credentials stored securley in the report" and it worked.

Edit, this workaround worked on Firefox and Chrome (I haven't tried I.E)

Comment: I had to click Apply after changing to Windows Integrated Security. Then switch back to Credentials stored securely in the report server, enter the password, then click Apply again.

Comment: Had this problem in Chrome 50+. Solved by switching to IE11, forcing it into IE8 mode (in Dev tools) and re-entering the password after every change.

Answer (score 5):

and I had this problem too.

initially I thought I had my `MYCOMPANY\reports` account password wrong, and I even tested the whole thing with a different account, only to find out the same problem was happening -

> "The password is not valid. Please retype the password".

then I used my own account with all its super powers and still the same error message, which then concluded that it was not related to AD or firewall.

what I did is, changed the settings to use `Windows Integrated Security`, tried it and applied even if it didn't work, then switched to some other option and again applied and saved.

ultimately I came back to `Credentials stored securely in the report server`, put the account and password, and it worked.

half a day wasted, but it worked.

I don't want anyone wasting their days with this, I am sure you can have a better option for that, given the opportunity.

hence the post here including the picture and all.
have a good day!!!

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Marcello Miorelli, you saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

It is a browser issue. We try it in IE and worked.

Comment: Worked for us using IE11, but not using EDGE nor Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Retyped the entire connectionstring.... No copy paste... and it worked. Its strange that when I put in the userid and password before and it showed the connection successful, but the credentials just wouldn't stick. Typed the connectionstring manually and it worked.

Comment: Sounds like there may have been a hidden character

Answer (score 1):

Gosh this thing has been bugging me for yonks!  I even went so far as to create a replacement data source and then used some voodoo scripts to go and re-associate the RDL's (Which only worked during testing I might add, but gained plenty experience with the inner workings of the database structures).

Switching focus to "Credentials not required" authentication method and back worked for me though.  And this works in IE (In my experience SSRS web manager is too finiky on non-Microsoft browsers).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue even with IE, and finally got it resolved as it was a line return or space on the connection string. just re-typed it again and it saved the password correctly after that.

weird that "test connection" worked all the time but after apply, it showed invalid password if I retried the "test connection"

Answer (score 0):

Used Edge and still same. Unchecked the box and let the windows account go in as SQL Account. Finally got the error in SQL Server logs as the login is windows and cannot be used as SQL.

Checked back the checkbox and it worked. I have no idea why such thing happened though.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for IE Edge or IE 11: Open the developers console (F12) and change the compatibility from Edge to IE 10.

It still works oddly, but switching radio buttons helps refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with this same issue for a while today, and tried all of the suggestions above.  None of them worked, but I did find a solution:

The service account I was using needed to be granted Allow Local Log On in Group Policy.