# updating Window login on SSRS data source

Tags: authentication, reporting-services, datasource

I need to update an existing SSRS data source with a new Window login. This is what my current data source setting looks like. I crossed out the current user name.

[image: Current data source setting]

My company's Windows admin wants me to use a new login. So I entered the new Username and even before I get to test my new connection, it immediately displays that red message saying, "The password is not valid. Please retype the password". So I put in what I am 100% sure is the correct password and hit the "Test Connection" button and I don't even see it trying to connect. That red message does not go away, and in the end, I am not able to update this existing data source with the new Window login.

[image: Trying to update to a new Windows login]

Can anyone duplicate this behavior? And how do I update this existing data source?

Comment: [Old answer here, what turned out to be browser javascript issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37045243/3585500)

Comment: Oh my goodness. Yes, seems fiddling around with those radio buttons and coming back to the option I want seems to have worked. So retarded. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.